# button and text offset HTML

Tags: html, button, text

This is my first post here. I am working on a website and I have used a table to space out different links but however I am trying to put a button next to a number that will be updated through my database. My problem is that the text and the button are offset and I can't get them to be level with each other. any ideas?

I can not post images as I do not have 10 reputation...

```
<tr>
    <td><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""/></td>
    <td>

    <strong><font size="8">3.5</font></strong>
    </td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" id="XYZ" class="btn btn-info btn-lg rateme" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Rate it!</button>

    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.example.com">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Visit Site!</button>
      </a>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: if you upload the image to an image sharing tool you can post the link, up to 2 links are allowed for new users. 
Is this a vertical alignment problem?

Comment: Just to let you know the `font` tag is obsolete and no longer should be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font.  Also you shouldn't use tables for layout (unless making an email template)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a vertical alignment problem, to fix it simply add the following attribute to your `<font>` tag:

```
style="vertical-align: middle;"
```

So your finished `<font>` tag should look like:

```
<font size="6" style="vertical-align: middle;">3.5</font>
```

And all together it should come out looking like:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""/></td>
    <td>

    <strong><font size="6" style="vertical-align: middle;">3.5</font></strong>
    </td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" id="XYZ" class="btn btn-info btn-lg rateme" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Rate it!</button>

    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.example.com">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Visit Site!</button>
      </a>
      </td>
  </tr>
```